# Issue combining two cypher queries with UNION

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I ran into the following problem when combining two cypher queries on [console.neo4j.org](http://console.neo4j.org)

The query:

```
MATCH (p1:Crew)-[r_pfq]->(fq:Crew)
WHERE fq.name IN ["Neo", "Morpheus"]
RETURN distinct(p1) AS person, count(r_pfq) AS friend_score, collect(fq.name) AS friends
ORDER BY friend_score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

works fine, as does

```
MATCH (f:Crew)<-[r_fqf]-(fq:Crew)
WHERE fq.name IN ["Neo", "Morpheus"]
WITH distinct(f), count(r_fqf) AS weight
ORDER BY weight DESC
LIMIT 10
MATCH f<--(p:Crew)
RETURN distinct(p) AS person, sum(weight) AS friend_score, collect(f.name) AS friends
ORDER BY friend_score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Now when I try to combine the query results using the `UNION` command, i.e.

```
MATCH (p1:Crew)-[r_pfq]->(fq:Crew)
WHERE fq.name IN ["Neo", "Morpheus"]
RETURN distinct(p1) AS person, count(r_pfq) AS friend_score, collect(fq.name) AS friends
ORDER BY friend_score DESC
LIMIT 10
UNION
MATCH (f:Crew)<-[r_fqf]-(fq:Crew)
WHERE fq.name IN ["Neo", "Morpheus"]
WITH distinct(f), count(r_fqf) AS weight
ORDER BY weight DESC
LIMIT 10
MATCH f<--(p:Crew)
RETURN distinct(p) AS person, sum(weight) AS friend_score, collect(f.name) AS friends
ORDER BY friend_score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I get the error

```
Error: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Unknown identifier `weight`.
```

Can anyone provide me with an explanation why these query results can not be combined and how to properly do so? Why is the identifier known when running both queries separately but unknown in a UNION-combined query?

Comment: Did you forget a second UNION statement?  In the query you pasted in the bottom, look about 2/3rds through, and it says "LIMIT 10 MATCH f<--(p:Crew)" -- I think you need another UNION there because MATCH after LIMIT makes no sense.

Comment: well, probably LIMIT 10 isn't too useful but I thought that MATCH after LIMIT would just take those 10 results and apply the MATCH condition on.
In any way, removing the LIMIT won't change anything about the unknwon identifier issue. In fact, the `UNION` query only works if I remove the `ORDER BY` statements in BOTH parts of the query (above and below the `UNION` statement). I don't get why the two queries are interpreted differently when connected by UNION when in fact i only want to results to be combined...?

Comment: I'm not talking about the usefulness of LIMIT and ORDER BY, I'm saying that as your query is presently stated, it looks syntactically incorrect to me.  That last MATCH is misplaced in any case.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

The following simpler query is basically equivalent, except that the second query in the `UNION` does *not* ORDER BY `weight`. This is because we are already ordering by the derived `friend_score`, so it seemed redundant. Also, in order for a variable to be included in the ORDER BY clause, it has to be in the RETURN clause -- but the first query in the UNION does not have a `weight` variable, which would have violated the requirements for a legal UNION statement.

In addition, there is a second WITH clause in the second query because you have to define the variables used in an ORDER BY clause (like `friend_score`) *before* the RETURN clause!

```
MATCH (p1:Crew)-[r_pfq]->(fq:Crew)
WHERE fq.name IN ["Neo", "Morpheus"]
RETURN DISTINCT (p1) AS person, count(r_pfq) AS friend_score, collect(fq.name) AS friends
ORDER BY friend_score DESC 
LIMIT 10
UNION
MATCH (p:Crew)-->(f:Crew)<-[r_fqf]-(fq:Crew)
WHERE fq.name IN ["Neo", "Morpheus"]
WITH f, count(r_fqf) AS weight, p
WITH f, sum(weight) AS friend_score, p
RETURN DISTINCT (p) AS person, friend_score, collect(DISTINCT (f).name) AS friends
ORDER BY friend_score DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: oddly, this query gives me the same `Error: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Unknown identifier 'weight'.`

Comment: @cybersam: How can we order by on total result of union, limit to total result?

Comment: I don't see a way to do that in Cypher.

Comment: thanks for your solution. In fact I tried something similar before and the problem with my data is, that `MATCH (p:Crew)-->(f:Crew)<-[r_fqf]-(fq:Crew)` takes REALLY long and so I wanted to restrict the query by limiting the query by only using the nodes with a large score between (f:Crew)<-[r_fqf]-(fq:Crew). Is there any other way to do this?